# codesign コマンドを実行すると errSecInternalComponent エラーが発生する

Tags: xcode, macos

自作のアプリに実行可能バイナリーを組み込もうとしています。
しかしそのままでは、公証を得るときにエラーになるので、`codesign`で事前に署名をしようとしたのですが、

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --options runtime --sign "Apple Development: XXXX (XXXX)" open_jtalk
```

と、`codesign`コマンドで`runtime`オプションを付けると、

```
open_jtalk: errSecInternalComponent
```

と、内部でエラーが起きていると言われ、署名が出来ません。

```
securyty unlock-keychain login.keychain
```

など、試して見たのですがエラーは出続けます。
どなたか解決方法をご存じないでしょうか？

環境はM1 Macbook Pro 2021 OSはMac OS 12.2です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local`下で作業したのが不味かったらしく、
`sudo`が必要ないビルドディレクトリーで実行したら成功しました。
ビルドディレクトリーで署名した後、`sudo cp open_jtalk /usr/local/bin`で上書きしたところ行けました。